# CSS not included in index.html

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have this webpack.config.js:

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = [{
entry: ['./app/clientside/app.scss', './app/clientside/app.js'],
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Caching',
    }),
],
output: {
path: __dirname + '/private_html/_app/dist',
publicPath: '',
filename: '[contenthash].bundle.js'
},
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[contenthash].bundle.css',
        },
      },
      { loader: 'extract-loader' },
      { loader: 'css-loader' },

                { loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                         plugins: () => [autoprefixer()]
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        implementation: require('sass'),
                        sassOptions: {
                            includePaths: ['./node_modules']
                        }
                    }
                },
    ]
  },
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
    },
     ] },
}];
```

The css and js files are generated, but in the index.html only the js file is included:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Caching</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<script src="dd9a13efe757661de1fe.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected to have link-element referencing the css file. I tried google but can't seem to find the right direction/ keywords. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably consider using [MiniCssExtractPlugin][1] for this purpose which together with the HtmlWebpackPlugin, would allow you to get the link tag in your HTML files, pointing to your CSS files.

I am quoting from the HtmlWebpackPlugin [documentation][2]:

> If you have any CSS assets in webpack's output (for example, CSS extracted with the MiniCssExtractPlugin) then these will be included with  tags in the  element of generated HTML.

You can also check out this SO [answer][3] that suggests some additional ways to inline CSS in HTML.

If you want, you can share a link to your project, and I can try to assist you more specifically.
[1]: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/
[2]: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/
[3]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50770543/6098812

Comment: Thx for pointing me in this direction. I did try MiniCssExtractPlugin, but aparrently the order of the loaders matters much. Thanks for helping, it is solved now!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I set `publicPath: '/'` in webpack config file which cause this and remove that line made my css apply correctly